# Can't access network path of localhost specified with a host

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-8

I use Windows.

Using Run window, I type `\\127.0.0.1` and enter. Viola, a window appears that shows my shared folder, a network view of my PC.

Now I add a simple DNS entry to the `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file, to give the 127.0.0.1 a name.

```
127.0.0.1     storage
```

Now again using Run window, I type `\\storage`. This time however Windows asks for credentials (username/password).

I'm using Microsoft Account to log into my Windows machine. Why using a name to access local host triggers credentials, while it's mapped to localhost IP?

Comment: When you ping storage, do you definitely get 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: Does the same happen if you use localhost?

Comment: @netniV, yes, 100% sure. For localhost it's OK.

Comment: Have you tried changing the name to make sure it isn't the name itself ?

Comment: @netniV, yep, I tried many names. The setup is very simple. You can test it.

Answer (score -2):

**First ask**
In Windows OS protected \etc\hosts dir.

Solution;

- copy \etc\hosts to a spesific dir,
- remove \etc\hosts,
- change copied hosts file,
- and recopy \etc\hosts file.

**Second question**

do yo setup any webserver?